# Delay in Responsive layout?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I would like to know how do you create the "delay" in Responsive design?

What I mean is, take the site [awwwards.com](http://www.awwwards.com) as an example. When you reduce the width of the browser there is a bit of a delay for the site to respond.

I would of imagined the code being this:

```
html, body {transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;}
```

but clearly it isnt (...or is it?!)

Just want to apply this effect on my own site which is [Blue Harlequin](http://www.blueharlequin.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;`  to your `.w` css class like this

CSS:

```
.w {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;
   }
```

Because the .w is the container for all your elements so add the the transition to that class will make the layout as how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It does have `transition: width 0.3s linear 0s;` but it on the `wrapper div`.